# Real solution of $\sin (\cos (\sin x)) = \cos(\sin (\cos x))$.

Tags: calculus

The number of real slution of the equation $\sin (\cos (\sin x)) = \cos(\sin (\cos x))\;.$ where $x\in \left[\; 0,\pi \right]$

Solution:: Case (I) :: Let $f(x) = \sin (\cos (\sin x)) - \cos(\sin (\cos x))\;, $ where $\displaystyle  0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Now Diff. both side w. r to $x\;,$ we get

$f^{'}(x) = -\cos(\cos(\sin x))\cdot \sin(\sin x)\cdot \cos x -\sin(\sin (\cos x))\cdot (\cos(\cos x))\cdot \sin x <0\displaystyle \; \forall x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

So $f(x)$ is Strictly Decreasing function.

So exactly one root of $f(x) = 0$ in $x\displaystyle \in \left[\; 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\; \right].$

Now I did not understand How can i find real solution of $f(x) = 0$ in $\displaystyle x\in \left[\; \frac{\pi}{2}\;, \pi\right]$

Comment: Have you looked at the graph yet?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $g(x)$ be the difference of those two functions. Prove that $g(r) = g(\pi/2+r)$. (So $g(x)$ is symmetric about $\pi/2$.) Then prove that $g(x)$ has period $\pi$.